# Definition of space $L^2(\mu)$ where $\mu$ is a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb R$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb R$ with compact support. Consider the space $L^2(\mu)$. It is the first time that I meet this space (usually I have $L^2(\mathbb R)$). Is it still a Banach space? Is it still a Hilbert space? By what norm and scalar product definitions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any $L^2$ space is a Hilbert space (and thus a Banach space).

Comment: @Math1000, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the definitions that you know from Lebesgue integration on $\mathbb{R}$ carry over, with integration against the Lebesgue measure replaced by integration against $\mu$. Most of the core theorems go through as well. This is covered in any decent measure-theoretic real analysis text, e.g. Royden and Fitzpatrick.

Comment: With $(f,g)=\int_{\mathbb R} f (t) \overline{g}(t) d\mu(t)$ as scalar product for $L^2(\mu)$?

Comment: @Lely Correct. ${}$